# Removing a program from the Microsoft Windows 7's native window switcher

Tags: windows-7, window-manager, alt-tab

On Microsoft Windows 7, hitting  <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>TAB</kbd> opens the  Microsoft Windows 7's native window switcher. Is there any way to configure it in such a way that it never display windows from a given program? E.g., I would like it to contain no windows from Google Chrome.

---

Microsoft Windows 7's native window switcher =

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Disable Aero Peek in Computer, Advanced System Properties, Performance features

https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-disable-alttab-preview-in-windows-7/

Comment: Thanks, can one selectively choose which program not to preview, while keeping the alt+tab working for other programs?

Comment: No, I do not think so. The function covers all programs.

Comment: If Chrome is not desirable in this situation, perhaps uninstall it and use IE in Windows 7